# How to change the hint text of search box in action bar using xml menu in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am using action bar using `AppCompactActivity`. I implemented search box in the action bar successfully. But I have a small problem with that. I want to change the hint text in the search box.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

This is my menu.xml with search item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/office_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="97"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

This is how I set menu with search feature for action bar:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.office_main_menu, menu);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.office_action_search).getActionView();
        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I change hint text of search box?

Comment: Change android:title="Search" to some other string

Comment: I tried it. But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the hint of the `SearchView` with the method `setQueryHint`.

Modify your code like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.office_main_menu, menu);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.office_action_search).getActionView();
        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setQueryHint("Your custom hint");
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add the following

```
<style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Then what I have to assign it to ?

Comment: <style name="ActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

I did a little different. In my case I use **setText** method of **SearchView.SearchAutoComplete** in this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchAutoComplete.setText("Type your music...");

    // rest of code 
    .....
}
```